# Why LinkButton inside GridView which is present in Updatepanel not firing OnClientClick event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, asplinkbutton

I have placed my GridView inside the Updatepanel and there I have defined few columns with one LinkButton. But for that LinkButton **OnClientClick** event is not firing. Instead it's doing a postback.
Following is the Code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:GridView ID="gvUnmappedICD" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No Records are added yet."
             OnRowCommand="gvUnmappedICD_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gvUnmappedICD_RowDataBound">
          <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemove" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("KEYWORD") %>' CommandName="remove" ClientIDMode="AutoID"
                        OnDataBinding="lnkRemove_DataBinding" OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete this?");' ToolTip="Click to Remove this record." Text="Remove" />
                 </ItemTemplate>
          </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This LinkButton with the ID **lnkRemove** should display a confirm message box when user clicks on it. But it's not showing it.
I have tried registering the Asynchronous PostBack event to this from code behind as follows:

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lbRemove);
```

Kindly anyone help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a **PostBackTrigger**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server">
            <asp:GridView ID="gvUnmappedICD" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No Records are added yet."
         OnRowCommand="gvUnmappedICD_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gvUnmappedICD_RowDataBound">
      <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
             <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemove" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("KEYWORD") %>' CommandName="remove" ClientIDMode="AutoID"
                    OnDataBinding="lnkRemove_DataBinding" OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete this?");' ToolTip="Click to Remove this record." Text="Remove" />
             </ItemTemplate>
      </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkRemove" />
            </Triggers>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Hi @vakeel, your answer will cause the following error. `A control with ID 'lnkRemove' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.`

Answer (score 0):

Please use this on link button's `OnClientClick`

```
 OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete this?");return false;'
```